# Indexing embedded mongoDB documents (in an array) with Solr

Tags: mongodb, solr, indexing

Is there any way, how I can make Solr index embedded mongoDB documents? We already can index top-level values of keys in a mongo document via mongo-connector, pushes the data to Solr.

However, in situations like in this structure which represents a post:

```
{
   author: "someone", 
   post_text : "some really long text which is already indexed by solr",
   comments : [
        {
            author:"someone else"
            comment_text:"some quite long comment, which I do not 
                          know how to index in Solr"
        },
        {
            author:"me"
            comment_text:"another quite long comment, which I do not 
                          know how to index in Solr"
        }
   ]
}
```

This is just an example structure. In our project, we handle more complicated structures, and sometimes, the text we want to index is nested on a second or third level (depth, or what is the formal name for it).

I believe that there is a community of mongoDB + Solr users and so that this issue must have been adressed before, but I was unable to find good materials, that would cover this problem, if there is a nice way, how to handle this or whether there is no solution and workarounds have yet to be founded (and maybe you could provide me with one)

For a better understanding, one of our structures have at top level key that has for its value an array of some several analysis results, where one of them has an array of singular values, that are parts of the result. We need to index these values. E.g. (this is not the actual data structure, we use):

```
{... 
    Analysis_performed: [
        {
            User_tags: 
                [
                   {
                       tag_name: "awesome", 
                       tag_score: 180
                   },
                   {
                       tag_name: "boring", 
                       tag_score: 10
                   }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case we would need to index on the tag names. There is a possibility of us having a bad structure for storing the data, we want to store, but we thought hard about it and we think it's quite good. However, even if we switch to less nested information, we will most likely come across at least one situation where we will have to index information stored in embedded documents that are in an array and this is the question's main focus. Can we index such data with SOLR somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official 10gen mongo connector now supports flattening of arrays and indexing subdocuments.
See https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector

However for arrays it does something unpleasant like this. It would transform this document:

```
{ 
    "hashtagEntities" : [
        {
                "start" : "66",
                "end" : "81",
                "text" : "startupweekend"
        },
        {
                "start" : "82",
                "end" : "90",
                "text" : "startup"
        },
        {
                "start" : "91",
                "end" : "100",
                "text" : "startups"
        },
        {
                "start" : "101",
                "end" : "108",
                "text" : "london"
        }
    ]
}
```

into this:

```
{
    "hashtagEntities.0.start" : "66",
    "hashtagEntities.0.end" : "81",
    "hashtagEntities.0.text" : "startupweekend",
    "hashtagEntities.1.start" : "82",
    "hashtagEntities.1.end" : "90",
    "hashtagEntities.1.text" : "startup",
....
}
```

The above is very difficult to index in Solr - even more if you have no stable schema for your documents. We wanted something more like this:

```
{
    "hashtagEntities.xArray.start": [
      "66",
      "82",
      "91",
      "101"
    ],
    "hashtagEntities.xArray.text": [
      "startupweekend",
      "startup",
      "startups",
      "london"
    ],
    "hashtagEntities.xArray.end": [
      "81",
      "90",
      "100",
      "108"
    ],
}
```

I have implemented an alternative solr_doc_manager.py

If you want to use this, just edit the flatten_doc function in your doc_manager to this, to support such functionality:

```
def flattened(doc):
    return dict(flattened_kernel(doc, []))
def flattened_kernel(doc, path):
    for k, v in doc.items():
        path.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for inner_k, inner_v in flattened_kernel(v, path):
                yield inner_k, inner_v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for inner_k, inner_v in flattened_list(v, path).items():
                yield inner_k, inner_v
            path.pop()
        else:
            yield ".".join(path), v
        path.pop()        
def flattened_list(v, path):
    tem = dict()
    #path2 = list()
    path.append(str("xArray"))            
    for li, lv in enumerate(v):                
        if isinstance(lv, dict):
            for dk, dv in flattened_kernel(lv, path):
                got = tem.get(dk, list())
                if isinstance(dv, list):
                    got.extend(dv)
                else:
                    got.append(dv)
                tem[dk] = got
        else:
            got = tem.get(".".join(path)+".ROOT", list())
            if isinstance(lv, list):
                got.extend(lv)
            else:
                got.append(lv)
            tem[".".join(path)+".ROOT"] = got
    return tem
```

In case you do not want to lose data from array, which are not sub-documents, this implementation will place the data into a "array.ROOT" attribute. See here:

```
{
    "array" : [
            {
                    "innerArray" : [
                            {
                                    "c" : 1,
                                    "d" : 2
                            },
                            {
                                    "ahah" : "asdf"
                            },
                            42,
                            43
                    ]
            },
            1,
            2
    ],
}
```

into:

```
{
    "array.xArray.ROOT": [
      "1.0",
      "2.0"
    ],
    "array.xArray.innerArray.xArray.ROOT": [
      "42.0",
      "43.0"
    ],
    "array.xArray.innerArray.xArray.c": [
      "1.0"
    ],
    "array.xArray.innerArray.xArray.d": [
      "2.0"
    ],
    "array.xArray.innerArray.xArray.ahah": [
      "asdf"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a question like this a couple months ago. My solution is to use doc_manager.
You can use solr_doc_manager (upsert method), to modify document posted into solr. For example, if you have

```
ACL: {
    Read: [ id1, id2 ...  ]
}
```

you can handle it something like

```
def upsert(self, doc):
    if ("ACL" in doc) and ("Read" in doc["ACL"]):
        doc["ACL.Read"] = []
        for item in doc["ACL"]["Read"]:
            if not isinstance(item, dict):
                id = ObjectId(item)
                doc["ACL.Read"].append(str(id))
    self.solr.add([doc], commit=False)
```

It adds new field - ACL.Read. This field is multivalued and stores list of ids from ACL : { Read: [ ... ] }

If you do not want to write you own handlers for nested documents, you can try another mongo connector. Github project page https://github.com/SelfishInc/solr-mongo-connector. It supports nested documents out of the box.

Comment: So we are thinking about using this connector in production environment - do you think the project is ok and reliable? Is it used somewhere else in production?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I want to index/store in Solr complicated documents. My approach was to modify the  the JsonLoader to accept complicated json documents with arrays/objects as values.

It stores the object/array and then flatten it and  indexes the fields.

e.g  basic example document

```
   {
        "titles_json":{"FR":"This is the FR title" , "EN":"This is the EN title"} ,
        "id": 1000003,
        "guid": "3b2f2998-85ac-4a4e-8867-beb551c0b3c6"
   }
```

It will store

```
titles_json:{
               "FR":"This is the FR title" , 
               "EN":"This is the EN title"
            }
```

and then index fields

titles.FR:"This is the FR title"
titles.EN:"This is the EN title"

Not only you will be able to index the child documents, but also when you perform a search on solr you will receive the original complicated structure of the document that you indexed.

If you want to check the source code, installation and integration details with your existing solr, check

http://www.solrfromscratch.com/2014/08/20/embedded-documents-in-solr/

please note that I have tested this for solr 4.9.0

M.

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and the way the mongo connector flattens subdocuments and arrays in the current version?

Comment: Sorry I never worked with mongo connector but i guess it is flattening the json and then send it to solr. On my solution you do the same thing but also you keep the original structure of the json document on the response. Furthermore you can import json data from everywhere not just mongo [i am importing from db].